# Modify file using script(Python,shell)

Tags: python-3.x, shell

How i can modify a ttl or a text file?

File format is in the picture:

[image]

First i am searching for those lines which starts with some special character for example #, once i get that line i have to change(add/update) one of its property with one of its another property.

The number of lines and their property could be in 100s.

I have this kind of data in 100 in number in a file and for each segment i have to check first line if it is correct then have to modify the first line. 
i.e. have to replace "dataput"(part of the url) from "datataken"(part of its parameter)

what are the possible ways i can achieve this.
This is i tried so far

```
import json
filename = "file.ttl"
commands = {}

with open(filename) as fh:

    for line in fh:
        command, description = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        commands[command] = description.strip()

print(json.dumps(commands, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

My ttl file looks like.
This is "A" segment of file and in the file there 1000s of segments are there

```
URL/DataPut
label1:data1 label2:data2 label3:data3,
label4:Service ;
  label4:data4 label5:data8                
  label4:data5 URL2                   
  label4:data6 "Test2Label ;                   
  label4:data7 "dataTaken"@                
    "data"@ .
```

Comment: Please provide any code attempts you have done so that we can help you

Comment: I am trying two solution for this : First : convert the file to JSON file then change content of it, but i am not sure can we convert ttl file to json however i am able to convert txt file                                                                                 2nd sol:import json
filename = "file.ttl"
commands = {}
with open(filename) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        command, description = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        commands[command] = description.strip()
print(json.dumps(commands, indent=2, sort_keys=True))this is just the modification i am trying ton simple txt file

Comment: Unless you provide some code on how you are doing these solution, it's hard to help you

Comment: Update the answer with the solution for better readability

Comment: Update the question with the code, the code is not readable in comment section

Comment: updated, not in perfect way bro :(

Comment: Also provide an example of how your file.ttl looks like

Comment: Again, Update the question with the example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191597/discussion-between-raj-and-devesh-kumar-singh).